# Win8 Firewall Apps blocked

Tags: windows, firewall

i set the Win8 Advanced Firewall to "Block all outgoing connections". Problem is now i can get neither the winstore nor my mail apps to access my microsoft account data (e.g. outlook.com email or sign in to the store). My other email account works fine. Display of the winstoreapps works, too.

The following are allowed to send through the firewall:

Services:

- wlidsvc (Signin assistent for microsoft accounts)
- WSService (windows store service)

AppPackages:

- MicrCommunicationsApps (default in the firewall)

Programs:

- C:\ProgramFiles\WindowsAppsmicrosoft.windowscommunicationsapps_16.4.4406.1205_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\LiveComm.exe
  (seems to be always running and has the same icon as mail)

Am I missing something?

Comment: I don't understand the problem.  You block all outgoing connections and expect these features to work?

Comment: I guess he wants to know what exceptions to create so that those features work.

Comment: Windows Firewall is good but it is missing the most useful outbound rules. It is quite hard to create them manually. How can we create rules for win10 apps?